# AssetBundle.LoadAsset is always returning NULL

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, assetbundle

I am unable to load asset as Gameobject from Assest bundle . It is returning null

```
    yield return www;
    AssetBundle bundle = www.assetBundle;
    if (www.error == null)
    {
        GameObject tv = (GameObject)bundle.LoadAsset("tv");
        //yield return tv;
        //GameObject santaasset = Instantiate(bundle.LoadAsset("tv", typeof(GameObject)) as GameObject);
        Debug.Log(bundle); // returns tv           
        Debug.Log(tv);//return null
        Instantiate(tv); 
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log(www.error);
    }
```

[image]

updated : 
Before 
[image: Before generating]
After
[image: After Generating]

Comment: What type of object is "tv". Can you select it and post a screenshot of it?

Comment: Its a plain file with no extension created using this method http://aarlangdi.blogspot.in/2016/04/unity-tutorial-loading-3d-asset-from.html

Comment: What's the file extension?

Comment: Its .obj . after generating assest bundle it doesn't have any extension .

Comment: Ok. I still need to see a screenshot of it. Select the "tv" object before generating bundle and then post a screenshot of the Project and Inspector tabs. I will use these two images to determine if there is anything wrong.

Comment: added images ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `AssetBundle.LoadAsset` is returning null because you don't have an Object named "tv" in the AssetBundle you are loading.

**1**.Make sure that the spelling it correct or that you are passing the correct object to the `LoadAsset` function. This is case-sensitive.

**2**.You must make sure that your object "tv" is added to the AssetBundle before building the AssetBundle.

Let's say that the name of your AssetBundle is `"house"` and the object you want to add to it is `"tv"`, select the `"tv"` object and change the AssetBundle option to `"house"`. See the the image below for reference:

[image]

---

In your case, the problem is **#1**. The name of your AssetBundle is `"tv"` and you want to load an Object called `"1.obj"`. Pass `"1"` to the `LoadAsset` function not `"tv"`.